# More memory to javascript client

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am making a javascript script and it requires large amounts of ram. Maybe like 100MB of ram. I need to make a large array on the client. Is there a html tag to give the script more memory?
Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Shapes and Stuff </title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var arr = [];
    loopWhileConditionIsTrue()
    {
        arr.add(new Object);
    }
</script>
```

The code does run, it just gets SUPER slow before I finish appending the array.
http://sulicat.com/gsim/gsim.html

Comment: Is something going wrong now? Such as an out-of-memory error?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: @torazaburo No. it hits a wall around 80Mb. BTW I am appending the object to the array dynamiccaly

Comment: try this [doc](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/).

Comment: 100 Mb is not very much. It shouldn't crash because of that. It's more likely that there's just a bug in the script.

Comment: "it hits a wall around 80Mb" --- what does it exactly mean? The ES standard does not standardise the "hitting a wall" JS behaviour.

Comment: How many times is it actually looping?

Comment: @zerkms 'hitting a wall' is all but stopping

Comment: Please expand the code snippet - as it stands it has little value to the post

Comment: @d512 depends on the file input that the user selects

Comment: @WilliamThompson JS cannot "just stop". If it silently stops - it's a bug in implementation and must be reported to the engine developers.

Comment: You can use various performance profiling tools such as those in devtools to help track down your problem. The other thing to check is whether the processing you are doing involves some kind of DOM change or other expensive operation each time you add something to the array, especially if such operation involving doing something with all the existing elements of the array, which quickly gets you into `O(n2)` territory.

Answer (score 1):

There's no HTML tag that dictates how much RAM your javascript gets access to. That's an OS level thing and not something you can control. To be honest, by today's standards 100 MB of RAM isn't all that much. Many of today's client based web applications will easily blow through that.

Basically you don't need to worry about it. Just write your program and let the runtime take care of it for you.

Also, remember that javascript memory is garbage collected so the system will reclaim the memory you have allocated but are no longer using.

Are you getting some kind of out of memory error? If so, you may want to post your code, the error message, and how much RAM the computer it's running on has.